# Form fields Validation on condition

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am trying to validate some fields on a form if a certain condition is met, The condition is if a checkbox is clicked then the fields below will be required and mandatory, if not then the fields are not mandatory. 
[image]

Comment: You could put an event handler of **onclick** on the checkbox and whenever the event handler is run you could check if the checkbox is ticked or not in an if statement and from there set the inputs to whatever you need them to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Back-End Validation**

You may use `required_if` Laravel validation rule

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

     'checkbox_field' => 'required|boolean',
     'otherField' => 'required_if:checkbox_field,1',
     // same for other fields

]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());
}

$validatedData = $validator->validated();
```

**Fron-End Validation**

You may also add required constraints using jQuery

```
$('#myCheckBoxId').change(function() {

    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        console.log("Checked");
        $("#myInput1ID").prop('required',true);
        $("#myInput2ID").prop('required',true);
        //...
    } else {
        console.log("Unchecked");
        $("#myInput1ID").removeAttr('required');
        $("#myInput2ID").removeAttr('required');
        //...
    }    

});
```

Check Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hg6r9q2t/9/)

Answer (score 3):

Laravel has a great Form Request Validation system. I strongly suggest to use that instead of using all validation logic in controllers.

Create a request with artisan console with following command;

```
php artisan make:request PageRequest
```

It will create a PageRequest class that extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;`

Looking like this;

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize(): bool
{
    return true; // you can use custom auth logic
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules(): array
{
    $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|numeric', // default inputs 
    ];

    // optional inputs
    if ($this->has('post_image'))
            $rules['post_image'] = 'required|image|max:500|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif';
        }
    }

    return $rules;
}

/**
 * Set the validation attributes
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function attributes(): array
{
    // you can use laravel's language system or just strings 
    return [
        'title' => trans('web.forms.title'),
        'post_image' => trans('web.forms.post_image'),
    ];
}
```

Then you can inject your Requests in resource controller like this;

```
public function store(PageRequest $request, $id) {}
```

Laravel docs [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Answer (score 2):

After send your form you can do it like this in controller:

```
public function sendForm (Request $request){
if($request->checkbox == "checked"){
 $request->validate([
  //Your validation rules.
  ]);
 }
}
```

Comment: Great @akbar but the issue is your solution happens after form submit. Should be before the submit

Comment: Ohhh.Its too simple.Html attribute like "required" can validate form in frontend.By this statement allow to say more harder solution first:1.You can define "onclick()" function on your submit button that call a function in javascript .and in that function you use "if clause" for checking of value of checkbox.if checkbox has been check you can add attributes like "required" to inputs. 2. you can add or remove "novalidation" attribute to your <form> tag. second one is better